# How to use isNumeric in jquery validation?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Problem with isNumeric validation with my form. **$.isNumeric($('input#director').val())** does not work. I want to check if the input value is only a string, and if the user entered numbers by mistake, the label error will appear. but problem is, it is not working.

```
$(function() {
   $('.error').hide();
   $(".submit").click(function() {
      $('.error').hide();
      var director = $("input#director").val();
      if(director=="" || ($.isNumeric($('input#director').val()))){
     $("label#director_error").show();
     $("input#director").focus();
     return false;
  }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you repeat `$('input#director').val()` when you already put it in the variable `director`?

Answer (score 4):

```
 if(director=="" && isNumeric(director).val())){ // and so on
```

Try this

Answer (score 2):

try this way:

```
$("#btnsubmit").click(function() 
{ 
    if($('input#director').val()==="" || $.isNumeric($('input#director').val()))
    {
      alert("error");
        //your other code 
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shree/cV4Pt/

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
   $('.error').hide();
   $(".submit").click(function() {
      $('.error').hide();
      var director = $("input#director").val();
      if(director=="" || isNumeric($('input#director').val())){
     $("label#director_error").show();
     $("input#director").focus();
     return false;
  }
   }
}
```

please use normal isNumeric function